# Adding Images to Test Results Giving Strange Results

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am adding images of the main window of my applications to the trx result files using TestContext.AddResultFile when tests fail. If I run the tests once I get correct results but when running the test more than once I end up with an image for each data row (image, image(1),image(2) etc...), which clutters up my results file.

Is there a better method for adding image files to the result file?

Comment: @Seva I ended up giving up on it.